# C# Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter not updating Item passed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I am using `MessagingCenter` to passe objects throu my pages, from my LoginPage to my MainPage.
Even tho the `object` is updated, when using it to my mainpage, the object seems to be null.

```
    public User sUser { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginPage, User>(this, "currentUserMainPage", (obj, item) =>
        {
            sUser = item;
            Debug.WriteLine("User updated from mainPage: " + sUser.firstName);
        });

        MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

        MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Home, (NavigationPage)Detail);
    }
```

When I check for the object before changing pages, even tho it is not null anymore, it returns me null.

```
public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
    {
        if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case (int)MenuItemType.Profile:
                    if(sUser == null)
                    {
                        MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(sUser)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ProfilePage(sUser)));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

**Edit:** here is the call from the LoginPage

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        try
        {
            //perform login
             MessagingCenter.Send(this, "currentUserMainPage", aUser.User);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: if you add a breakpoint in this line `sUser = item;` does it hit? Can you show the code when you're sending the message... Maybe the `MainPage` is another instance...

Comment: where is your `MessagingCenter.Send()`?

Comment: MessagingCenter.Send(this, "currentUserMainPage", aUser.User);

Comment: updated code on main post

Comment: You're sending the user in the `OnAppearing`? Not really following the code, if the `sUser` is `null`, you add the `LoginPage` with the `sUser` value `null` and in the `OnAppearing` you're sending `null`. When is `aUser` assigned/set

Comment: As you can see, the login process is commented out as it is unnecessary...

Comment: I am sure it is sent as, after sent on my MainPage, this line shows me the sUser informations Debug.WriteLine("User updated from mainPage: " + sUser.firstName);

Comment: there's really not enough context here to understand what you're doing, and your description of the problem is not very clear.  If you just want to share your User object throughout the app, adding it as a property on your App class would be a better approach.

Comment: @Jason it looks pretty clear to me but I guess because I am in the project, i undestand you. The loginpage is called, it performs the login process onAppearing . Then it just passes the User class back to the MainPage. The MainPage uses the User class passed to perform actions, look the switch...case loop.

Comment: This line here will always check null even when the sUser is passed throu messagin and updated.
if(sUser == null)...

Comment: @Alejandro Hi , If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can have a check with MessageCenter document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

When subscribing and sending message , we need to keep the count and type of paramater be the same .

The example as follow :

**Publish a Message :**  `MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", "John");`

**Subscribe to a message :**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + arg, "OK");
});
```

You will see that the first paramater is `MainPage` , and the second is `string` . They all need to set when publishing or subscribing .

**In addition** , using MessageCenter between different pages or classes , you can use `object` to replace or `MainPage` .

**Therefore** , shared code can be modified as follow :

Subscribing **MessageCenter** with `object` :

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, User>(this, "currentUserMainPage", (obj, item) =>
{
    sUser = item;
    Debug.WriteLine("User updated from mainPage: " + sUser.firstName);
});
```

And send message also with `object` :

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object,User>(this, "currentUserMainPage", aUser.User);
```